# How to manage Cache control options in a single place instead of having it at action method level using asp.net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have ASP.NETCORE 3.1 WEBAPI , Azure SQL server as the database for an application.

Instead of repeating the code ([ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]) as an attribute across multiple methods as shown below, I want to put it in Starup.cs ConfigureServices method:

**TestController.cs**

```
[HttpGet("{param1:long}", Name = "GetData")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestModel), 200)]
public IActionResult GetData(long param1)
    => Ok(_testService.GetData(param1));
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddFrameworkServices(this IServiceCollection services) => services.AddMemoryCache().AddRouting().Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true).AddMvc(op =>
{
    op.CacheProfiles.Add("Never", new CacheProfile()
    {Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true});
    op.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest));
    op.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent));
    op.Filters.Add(new ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(typeof(ErrorMsg), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).Services;
```

I removed [ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Never")] from the action method and validated and found cache headers are not displayed in the response even though it is mentioned in the Startup.cs.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code resolved the issue:

services

```
 .AddMvc(o =>
    {
        op.Filters.Add(new ResponseCacheAttribute { NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None });
    });
```

I validated the change and found working as expected